# Java converting object array to string array

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

So i've been trying to solve this issue for hours but cant seem to find an answer which would work.

i have an object array which stores flight information and i had to remove flights which had Valstybe: "Maldyvai"
so i made a new object array without them, but when i try to print it i get a memory location.

How do i convert the object array to string array?
even though i have a tostring method in my java class

```
package com.company;

import java.util.*;
import com.company.Isvestine.OroUostasKeleivis;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here

        OroUostasKeleivis Keleiviai1 = new OroUostasKeleivis("Skrydis","Washington","JAV","Tomas","tomaitis","Washington",5465);
        OroUostasKeleivis Keleiviai2 = new OroUostasKeleivis("Skrydis","Washington","Maldyvai","Tomas","tomaitis","Maldyvai",5466);
        OroUostasKeleivis Keleiviai3 = new OroUostasKeleivis("Skrydis","Washington","JAV","Tomas","tomaitis","Washington",5467);
        OroUostasKeleivis Keleiviai4 = new OroUostasKeleivis("Skrydis","Washington","Maldyvai","Tomas","tomaitis","Maldyvai",5468);
        OroUostasKeleivis Keleiviai5 = new OroUostasKeleivis("Skrydis","Washington","JAV","Tomas","tomaitis","Washington",5469);
        OroUostasKeleivis Keleiviai6 = new OroUostasKeleivis("Skrydis","Washington","Maldyvai","Tomas","tomaitis","Maldyvai",5470);
        OroUostasKeleivis Keleiviai7 = new OroUostasKeleivis("Skrydis","Washington","JAV","Tomas","tomaitis","Washington",5475);
        OroUostasKeleivis Keleiviai8 = new OroUostasKeleivis("Skrydis","Washington","Maldyvai","Tomas","tomaitis","Maldyvai",5476);
        OroUostasKeleivis Keleiviai9 = new OroUostasKeleivis("Skrydis","Washington","JAV","Tomas","tomaitis","Washington",5477);
        OroUostasKeleivis Keleiviai10 = new OroUostasKeleivis("Skrydis","Washington","JAV","Tomas","tomaitis","Washington",5488);

        OroUostasKeleivis[] keleiviai = new OroUostasKeleivis[10];

        keleiviai[0] = Keleiviai1;
        keleiviai[1] = Keleiviai2;
        keleiviai[2] = Keleiviai3;
        keleiviai[3] = Keleiviai4;
        keleiviai[4] = Keleiviai5;
        keleiviai[5] = Keleiviai6;
        keleiviai[6] = Keleiviai7;
        keleiviai[7] = Keleiviai8;
        keleiviai[8] = Keleiviai9;
        keleiviai[9] = Keleiviai10;

        for (OroUostasKeleivis keleiveliai:keleiviai) {
            System.out.println(keleiveliai);
        }

        System.out.println("test debug");
        OroUostasKeleivis[] keleiviaibemaldyvu = new OroUostasKeleivis[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        }
        System.out.println(IsstrintiMaldyvus(keleiviai));
        String convertedStringObject = IsstrintiMaldyvus(keleiviai) .toString();
        System.out.println(convertedStringObject );
    }

    static Object[] IsstrintiMaldyvus(OroUostasKeleivis[] keleiviai){

        OroUostasKeleivis[] keleiviaiBeMaldyvu = new OroUostasKeleivis[10];
        int pozicija = 0;

        for ( OroUostasKeleivis keleiveliai: keleiviai) {
            if (keleiveliai.getValstybe() != "Maldyvai"){
                keleiviaiBeMaldyvu[pozicija] = keleiveliai;
                pozicija++;
            }
        }
        return keleiviaiBeMaldyvu;

    }
}
```

Comment: did you remember to override the toString method in your class? if not, it'll take the inherited method from the Object class, which shows something like ClassName@358e74 ..

Comment: yes, I did override it

Comment: you are printing the array, you have to print the seperate Objects. for Arrays, there is no toString implementation

Answer (score 0):

> but when i try to print it i get a memory location

Yes, you will NOT have result as you expected, especially calling `toString()` with any array. See [documentation of `java.lang.Object.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) for more details.

### So how can we solve problem?

first, override `toString()` method in `OroUostasKeleivis` like this:

```java
class OroUostasKeleivis {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // your implementation here
        return null; // TODO: change here
    }
}
```

Second, you may do either way:

1. If you're interested in just print out, you can do that with `System.out.println(keleiveliai)` in for-each loop like you do.
2. If you're interested in converting `OroUostasKeleivis[]` to `String[]`, you can:

```java
// this requires Java 8 or later
String[] converted = Arrays.asList(keleiviai)
    .stream()
    .map(OroUostasKeleivis::toString)
    .toArray(String[]::new);

// then use `converted`
```

Comment: you solved the wrong problem. He called toString on an array, not on the content of it

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(IsstrintiMaldyvus(keleiviai)))`

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-tostring-in-java-with-examples/

It will print the array contents similar to how `ArrayList` would get printed if it had the same content.

Think of it as:
[ obj1.toString(), obj2.toString(), ... ]

Answer (score 0):

Using `java.util.Arrays#stream(T[])` filter and convert object array to string array and use `java.util.Arrays#toString(java.lang.Object[])` convert array to readable string.

```
 final String[] oroUostasKeleivis = Arrays.stream(keleiviai)
                .filter(
                        k -> k.getValStybe() != "Maldyvai"

                )
                //                or other convert code
                .map(OroUostasKeleivis::toString)
                .toArray(String[]::new);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(oroUostasKeleivis));
```